# Why won't SSI work in IIS?

Tags: iis, server-side-includes

I can't get IIS to respect my SSI directives - it just outputs the #include directive as if it were regular old html.

Here's the relevant data points:

- My file with the include directive is called index.html
- This is my directive: `<!-- #include
  file = "header.shtml" -->` (it
  doesn't work with `virtual` either.)
- The file being requested is in the
  same directory as the file being

  ## include-ed.
- The SSI module is installed.
- The SSINC-shtml handler
  mapping is present and enabled.

I think it might be some sort of permissions issue (read/write/execute), but I don't know where those settings are in IIS 7.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the file is called index.html, which is not mapped to the SSI handler by default.  Either:

1. Map the .html file extension to the SSI handler which brings up [another question](https://serverfault.com/questions/248120/is-it-ok-to-map-the-ssi-handler-to-html-files-in-iis) **OR**
2. Rename the file index.shtml

Answer (score 0):

In IIS Mgr, click on the Server / site node (whichever level is appropriate for your environment) and click Handler Mappings.  Double-click on the `SSINC-shtml` mapping, the click the `Request Restrictions...` button.  Check the settings in all 3 tabs there and see if you've got something set improperly.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "improperly"?  I saw that it has script access.

Answer (score -1):

Server-Side Includes are not enabled by Default in IIS 7 on Windows 7.

In Control Panel, Programs, Turn Windows features on off:

Check the option:

```
  Internet Information Services
    Application Development Features
      [x] Server-Side Includes
```

Comment: -1 for not reading that I have already installed the SSI module.

Comment: Did you also enable Common HTTP Features \ Static Content?